# How to solve situation where I need timestamp script to work on cell auto entry, not manual

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-timestamp

Can someone help me with this problem.

I have timestamp script running in google sheet and it work fine when I manually change value in cell. But I can't find any solution how to have timestamp working when entry in trigger cell is some auto data from formula or such.
Or maybe if someone have another solution.
What I'm doing now is, from sheet1 with Query transfer data to sheet2 when some change is made.

When new row is created in sheet2 I want to have date of entry for every row that is created in sheet2, and date need to be fix all the time.

Comment: Do you mean like a "date created" timestamp?

Comment: When Package is change in Sheet1, for example in December 2020 there is no package, but in January 2021 you enter new package, and financial change is made... I made Query to extract information I need in Sheet2 for every financial change. One more thing I need is, when new row is created in Sheet2 I want to have date of entry for every row that is created in Sheet2, and date need to be fix all the time.
I have script running in Sheet2 col A, but script work only when I manually change value in Sheet2 col B, if there is auto entry, script don't work.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13wZOqbW0KE3SyxtUR5aqP0OTJzqCbAajJurMLbcY_lw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm open for any solution, if there is another way to make auto date entry when new row is created.